# Android Location Manager Takes A Long Time Finding Longitude and Latitude

Tags: java, android, google-maps

The code I have works when it feels like it. It will either work straight away or will take a very long time, or not work at all. The code is as follow:

```
 locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
 locationLis = new LocationListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
           lat= location.getLatitude();
           log = location.getLongitude();
           locationManager.removeUpdates(locationLis);
      }
      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle){
      }
      @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
      }
      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
           System.out.println("Not Found");
      }
 };

 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationLis);
```

The device I am using to test is a Nexus 7 (2012)

Comment: Are you testing this in emulator? and while testing are you sure that gps is available..To  test it correctly, test the app under open sky..

Comment: Thanks @Lal for your reply, I am using a nexus 7 (2012) and I will try and test under open sky now

Comment: Great @GiovanniL.. Please do tell me the result..

Comment: @Lal it worked better outside because of the GPS provider, I have now updated it to Network Provider :D

Comment: Will you give an upvote if I add that as my answer..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use the `GPS_PROVIDER` I changed it to `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

This used the network to get the location rather than the GPS which is what took so long. The code was:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationLis);
```

and now reads:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationLis);
```

Answer (score 2):

That may be because your GPS is not getting fixed. Check for the GPS icon, It may be blinking. Thats purely because the GPS is not getting Fixed.

So, I strongly recommend you to **test the app under Open Sky**. This helps in fixing the GPS faster. And while testing under open sky, you can see that the GPS icon will stop blinking and remains steady.